# Slow Page Load Times

Tags: python, json, django, rest

I have a table which is populated via a RESTful `API` call to a database. For one particular table column, its data is pulled by referencing an `ID` from the main `API` call and then using said `ID` as a parameter for a second `API` call. However, there may be 1,000 or more rows of data in the table, so iterating through all these rows and performing the second `API` call is causing very slow page load times (up to 40 seconds). Is there any way I might handle this issue? I can limit the number of records returned per query, but ideally I would include all records available. Please let me know if any other information is needed.

views.py

```
cw_presales_engineers = []

for opportunity in opportunities:
    try:
        opportunity_id = str(opportunity['id'])
        presales_ticket = cwObj.get_tickets_by_opportunity(opportunity_id)
        if presales_ticket:
            try:
                cw_engineer = presales_ticket[0]['owner']['name']
                cw_presales_engineers.append(cw_engineer)
            except:
                pass
        else:
            cw_engineer = ''
            cw_presales_engineers.append(cw_engineer)
    except AttributeError:
        cw_engineer = ''

connectwise_zip = zip(opportunities, cw_presales_engineers)
```

Comment: Do you have the ability to create a new [experience API](https://xapi.com/overview/) that can do the iteration on the server side?

Comment: Does your API support filtering records by ID? If so, this could be used to coalesce find requests. So instead of doing `GET /posts/1` and `GET /posts/2` you could combine them to one query request `GET /posts?filter[id]=1,2`. This would reduce your issue to 1+1 instead of 1+n requests. 1+1 should be fine for most scenarios.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer I'm not familiar with xAPI, so I'm not sure yet. @jelhan I'm able to filter records, but I'm referencing `opportunity['id']` to pull records from an entirely different location. So the `URL` for each `API` call is different...would I still be able to coalesce find requests to two different locations?

Comment: @garmars You are only able to coalesce find requests if the API supports fetching multiple records by there ID. This is mostly achieved by filtering on a collection endpoint. If your API supports a different mechanism you are free to do that one.

Comment: @jelhan well I am requesting data at two different endpoints, so is there some method of handling this situation? Or would it depend entirely on the API?